# Issue with displaying images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-phone-7, xaml

OK, here's my issue :

- I've got a custom class, with a list of items - each of which has an image path associated with it
- I've added a folder WITH the images inside the project (so I suppose there are being added in the XAP too, huh?)
- When I'm trying to bind the Source of an image item in XAML, it's not working.

---

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Source="/AlbumArt/{Binding AlbumArt}"/>
                <StackPanel Width="311">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

---

**P.S.**

- I've also tried `Source="{Binding AlbumArt}"` but it's still not displaying anything.
- The craziest thing is that, if I set the Source to a specific image (e.g. `/AlbumArt/someImage.jpg`), the image seem to work fine in Visual Studio & the Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Binding works that way. If it is not possible to prepend the string `"/AlbumArt/"` to your image path property (which is `AlbumArt`), I would suggest using a converter to do so.

Also, formatting strings only works when the target property is a string so StringFormat is out. Someone correct me if I'm wrong about StringFormat

Answer (score 0):

If you have binding issues always check the output window for details. That is where information about binding errors is displayed.

This `Source="/AlbumArt/{Binding AlbumArt}"` won't work because it will just be treated as a string.

Without seeing your class it's hard to be certain but the property you're binding to ("AlbumArt") should be a `Uri` and not a `string` and it should be populated with a relative Uri to the image. That image should also be set to having the build action of Content.

Answer (score 0):

what you have to is this..

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
```

as you said you have list of items( i think it would be class that also having paths of images ) so make this property in this class and for every item put the path in this property for coresponding item.

```
private string _ImagePath;
public string ImagePath
{
   get
   {
     return _ImagePath;
   }
   set
   {
    _imagePath = value;

   }
}
```

it would be better if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your item class.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting more nesty.

```
private string _AlbumArt;
public string AlbumArt
{
   get
   {
     return _AlbumArt;
   }
   set
   {
if(_AlbumArt!=null)
    _AlbumArt=@"/AlbumArt/"+ value;

   }
}
```

and Binding

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Source="{Binding AlbumArt}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you've just used the wrong path, try this one....

`"/ApplicationName;component/AlbumArt/{Binding AlbumArt}"`

Replace the ApplicationName section with your applications name of course. MAKE SURE TO REPLACE SPACES IN IT WITH `%20`